# .NET Core MVC - renders accept Attribute String wrongly

Tags: c#, html, razor, asp.net-core-mvc

I have an Filechooser and in this Filechooser I set the accepted Property from a `ViewData`. Which works without problems. On another Site I have an Filechooser too, which uses the same `ViewBag`, but is not bound to an ViewModel.

```
var List<string> Allowed =new List<string>() { ".txt",".doc" };
...
ViewData["Allowed"]=String.Join(", ", Allowed.ToArray());
....
 <input asp-for="NewFiles" class="file-select" multiple accept=@ViewData["Allowed"]> //Works
....
 <input name="Files" id="Files" type="file" class="file-select" multiple class="file-select" accept=@ViewData["Allowed"]> //Does not work
```

In the first Variant the accept Attribute is rendered to: ".txt, .doc". While in the second One it will be: **".txt"**,.doc". Meaning only "txt" will be available in the Chooser.
Why?

I have used the Debugger to check what is in the `ViewData` and what will be written into the "accept" in the View and in both cases it is the same String.

How can I fix the second?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use double quotes:

```
<input name="Files" id="Files" type="file" multiple class="file-select" accept="@ViewData["Allowed"]">
```

This syntax will render the following `<input>` tag:

```
<input name="Files" id="Files" type="file" multiple class="file-select" accept=".txt, .doc">
```

Comment: lol, is there a reason why those two are differently rendered? Because I use a Taghelper in one and not in the other?

Comment: @EsoMoa: I understand it as different parsing rules for regular HTML attributes and the tag helpers. Anyway, I would not count on the tag helper parser, that it will do all the checks and will add missing quotes. The rule say that we should use the quotes for the helper too, like: `<input asp-for="NewFiles" class="file-select" multiple accept="@ViewData["Allowed"]">` . You can see examples in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/working-with-forms?view=aspnetcore-7.0#expression-names-and-collections).

Comment: @EsoMoa: Perhaps this will help you: [IntelliSense support for Tag Helpers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/tag-helpers/intro?view=aspnetcore-7.0#intellisense-support-for-tag-helpers)